# Finite differences and conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am using a Finite Difference scheme to solve a simple P.D.E. in conserved form:

$$\partial_t u = \partial_x (\partial_x u +au\partial_x u) = (1+a)\partial_x^2u +a(\partial_x u)^2 $$

$$\frac{u_{n+1,j} - u_{n,j}}{\Bbb dt} = (1+a) \frac{u_{n+1,j+1} - 2\, u_{n+1,j} + u_{n+1,j-1}}{\Bbb dx^2} + a \bigg(\frac{u_{n,j+1}-u_{n,j-1}}{2\, \Bbb dx}\bigg)^2$$

As you see, I use a fully implicit scheme for the diffusive part, and an explicit scheme for the first derivative bits (squared). It can easily be seen that the P.D.E. states the conservation of the integral of $u(x,t)$, because:

$$\partial_t \int_0^L u(x,t)\,\Bbb dx=\int_0^L\partial_x(\partial_x u +au\partial_x u)\,\Bbb dx=[\partial_x u +au\partial_x u]_0^L$$

So if I impose Neumann boundary conditions, $$\partial_xu\bigg|_{0,L}=0$$ the integral of $u(x,t)$ must be conserved. I implement the Neumann B.C. saying that:

which is second order (notice that I use three points to derive this, it is equivalent to approximating the function $u(x,t)$ at the boundary with a parabola).

Now, how could I estimate the error on the conservation of $\int_0^L u \,\Bbb x$ given $\Bbb dt$ and $\Bbb dx$?

Comment: did you check the analogous of the conservation in the discrete scheme?

Comment: I tried to impose conservation on the whole r.h.s, by discretising it in conserved form, i.e. as a first derivative, but that gives me an unstable thing (I see sawtooth modes entering the grid)

Comment: I edited the question to avoid getting too much into the detail of my specific problem, I hope that increases the interest.

Answer (score 0):

here is a scheme you can try to see if it conserves the mass better. i have not tried the scheme so i cant be sure.

$$\frac{{(dx)}^2}{dt}(u_j^{n+1} - u_j^n) = (1+au^n_{j+1/2})(u_{j+1}^n - u_j^n) + (1+au_{j-1/2}^n)(u_j^n - u_{j-1}^n), j = 0,1,\cdots M$$ where $u_{j+1/2}^n = {u_j^n + u_{j+1}^n \over 2}, u_{-1}^n = u_{1}^n, u_{M-1}^n = u_{M+1}^n.$

Comment: It seems to me that here the stiff term will have trouble, because there is no implicit part in your scheme.

Comment: I edited the question to avoid getting too much into the detail of my specific problem, I hope that rises the interest.